# Enabling console in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I wanted to know if there is any way to access a console object in Netbeans IDE via System.console(). right now its pointing to a null object. I looked it up in one of the previous stackoverflow posts and it said to enable the "console view", which unfortunately, i couldn't find in my IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some IDEs don't provide a console. Note that `System.console()` returns `null` in these cases. I seem to recall that NetBeans will not provide a console. You can run it from the command line instead.

Comment: yes it is working fine in command prompt... just not in IDE... isnt there any way around?